# Can I avoid a join for my select procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join

Here is a really simple example of a select procedure I'd like to create, although it's only partly done (it's pretty self-explanatory):

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.selectTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hashid int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _dob int, _stateid int, _stateid_status bit(1))
begin
  START TRANSACTION;

  SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `hashID` FROM MYDB.person;

  SELECT`id`, `id_status`, `criminal_status`, `hashID` FROM MYDB.id_crimes;

  SELECT `stateID`, `stateID_status`, `dob`, `hashID` FROM MYDB.dob_state;

  SELECT `create_time`, `update_time`, `hashID` FROM MYDB.timestamps;

  COMMIT;
end//
delimiter ;
```

What I'm looking for is the absolutely most concise way to select a record in its entirety, keeping it as a procedure. I'd really like to avoid joins on the tables, but I don't really see any way around doing a join on the hashID, given the abovementioned restrictions. Is there another way? Pointers? What would that look like in a procedure? I'd like to see someone's concise correction of what I want to do. :) 
Thanks!

Comment: `I'd really like to avoid joins on the tables` <-- WHY? Did someone sell you snake oil that all joins always slow down all queries no matter what?

Comment: No...it's for an experiment (comparing performance); I already have joins implemented. Not sure that whether or not someone has sold me "snake oil" is really relevant to my question, though. :)  If you want to demonstrate a super efficient way to use a join within the procedure, I'm happy to take a look anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.selectTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hashid int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _dob int, _stateid int, _stateid_status bit(1))
begin
  START TRANSACTION;

  SELECT @fn:=`first_name`, @ln:=`last_name`, @hid:=`hashID` FROM MYDB.person WHERE <condition>;

  SELECT @id:=`id`, @s:=`id_status`, @cs:=`criminal_status` FROM MYDB.id_crimes WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  SELECT @sid:=`stateID`, @sids:=`stateID_status`, @dob:=`dob` FROM MYDB.dob_state WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  SELECT @ct:=`create_time`, @ut:=`update_time` FROM MYDB.timestamps WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  COMMIT;

  SELECT @fn AS `first_name`, @ln AS `last_name`, @hid AS `hashID`,
         @id AS `id`, @s AS `id_status`, @cs AS `criminal_status`,
         @sid AS `stateID`, @sids AS `stateID_status`, @dob AS `dob`,
         @ct AS `create_time`, @ut AS `update_time`;
end//
delimiter ;
```

## Edit:

You can also use `SELECT <columns,...> INTO <variables,...>`:

You can use variables:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.selectTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hashid int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _dob int, _stateid int, _stateid_status bit(1))
begin
  START TRANSACTION;

  SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `hashID` INTO @fn, @ln, @hid FROM MYDB.person WHERE <condition>;

  SELECT `id`, `id_status`, `criminal_status` INTO @id, @s, @cs FROM MYDB.id_crimes WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  SELECT `stateID`, `stateID_status`, `dob` INTO @sid, @sids, @dob FROM MYDB.dob_state WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  SELECT `create_time`, `update_time` INTO @ct, @ut FROM MYDB.timestamps WHERE `hashID` = @hid;

  COMMIT;

  SELECT @fn AS `first_name`, @ln AS `last_name`, @hid AS `hashID`,
         @id AS `id`, @s AS `id_status`, @cs AS `criminal_status`,
         @sid AS `stateID`, @sids AS `stateID_status`, @dob AS `dob`,
         @ct AS `create_time`, @ut AS `update_time`;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @Lori I added an alternative using `SELECT INTO` which should not have that issue.

Comment: I believe you copied and pasted the exact same procedure twice above, if you want to take a look.

Comment: @Lori nope, all of the SELECT FROM are now SELECT INTO FROM.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. :)